# camera calibration using opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0, camera-calibration

i am doing camera calibration using opencv python. I have found the camera matrix using cv2.calibratecamera function but the camera matrices are diffrent for diffrent image
this is the code i am using-

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((7 * 7, 3), np.float32)
objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:7, 0:7].T.reshape(-1, 2)
#objp = objp*(2.4625)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = []  # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = []  # 2d points in image plane.

images = glob.glob('*.jpg')
print('hello')

for r12 in images:
    img = cv2.imread('r12.jpg')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7, 7), None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        print('yes')

        cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)

        # Draw and display the corners
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7, 7), corners, ret)
        cv2.imshow('img', img)
        cv2.waitKey(500)
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
#np.savez('coefficientsr',cameramatrixr = mtx,distcoeffsr = dist,rotationalvectorsr = rvecs,translationalvectorsr = tvecs)
print(mtx)
print(dist)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the reprojection error to see how accurate your parameters are for each calibration. Also make sure to use enough images and include varying angles of the object.

This tutorial shows how to calculate the reprojection error: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html